# URL and EMAIL Validation API in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In **Java**, 
We validate the URL pattern using the UrlValidator API.
`org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator` for URL validation.

Do we have something in kotlin to validate URL pattern?

I know Kotlin is 100% compatible with Java.

I don't want to use java library in kotlin code, because It will work only for one platform and will not work for other platforms.

Comment: Kotlin is backed up by Java's vast resources and llibraries. You can use any java api for that, they are 100% interoperable.

Comment: And I recommend checking [valiktor](https://github.com/valiktor/valiktor) and [konform](https://github.com/konform-kt/konform)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java libraries in your kotlin project.

> Existing Java code can be called from Kotlin in a natural way, and Kotlin code can be used from Java rather smoothly as well

```
InternetAddress("example@test.com").validate()
UrlValidator().isValid("http://example.com")
```

Refer [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)